# How can you group rows by 3 minute interval time stamps in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

How can you group rows by 3 minute interval time stamps in excel and make sure that the rows grouped are by the user name? I want to make sure to keep all the other column data as well not mentioned here.

I am hoping to do this by formula but if VBA, it's ok, I can add it.

```
Column A

timestamp
04/26/2017 01:00:04 PM
04/26/2017 01:00:10 PM
04/26/2017 01:00:11 PM
04/26/2017 01:00:11 PM
04/26/2017 01:00:14 PM
04/26/2017 01:00:32 PM
04/26/2017 01:00:35 PM

**Column B**

Username
Bob
Rick1
Tickman
Tickman
OStech
Bob
Rick
```

Comment: What do you mean by "group"?

Comment: Is your "timestamp" column an actual formatted date-time value, or is it text?  It's not at all clear what you mean by "group", so it would be very useful to add some representative "before" and "after" screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

It seems at least four people (myself included) out of sixteen don't understand the Q but a PivotTable allows options for the presentation of data:

[image: SO43769991 example]

Comment: Just two columns, A and B. There are a total of A:R columns, but I just presented two. Wanted to be able to group them by together instead of filtering. I am working with over 300,000 rows. I will try this when I get back to work tomorrow. My thanks!